# issueRef parameter in CashIssueFlow

Tags: corda, corda-flow

What's the main purpose of this "issueRef" parameter? And why the samples just put

```
OpaqueBytes.of("1".getBytes()
```

or

```
OpaqueBytes.of(0x01)
```

Is it just to link an issued asset to an issuer? Could one give me a usage example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a reference to allow Corda users to link the on-ledger assets they hold to real-world assets.